# Subscribing to route params is not working

Tags: angular

I have a page `/news` with parameter `page`. For example: `/news;page=2`. I don't want to reinitialize news page when page is changed. I just want to subscribe to page changes, I've tried this code:

```
export class NewsPage implements OnInit {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            ...
        });
    }
}
```

If `/news` page is opened and I navigate to `/news` page with different page parameter (`this.router.navigate(['/news', {page: 2} ])`) then the page is reinitialized (the page is destroyed and created again).

But if I use queryParams (`/news?page=2`) instead of params (`/news;page=2`) then everything works fine:

```
export class NewsPage implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            ...
        });
    }
}
```

If I call `this.router.navigate(['/news'], {queryParams: {page: 2}} )` then the page is NOT reinitilized. Just subscribe callback is executed. Why does it happen?

Here is my routing file:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/home", pathMatch: "full" },
  {
    path: "news",
    loadChildren: "./pages/news/news.module#NewsPageModule"
  }
  { path: "**", redirectTo: "/page404" }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Here is my news page module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: NewsPage
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [NewsPage]
})
export class NewsPageModule {}
```

Comment: can you share your routing file and why you are not injecting constructor(router: Router) {
    }?

Comment: Yes. I updated the question. I inject router in constructor. It was just an example

Comment: still missing news module routes :)

Comment: sorry. Updated again

Comment: Please add the routing file of your `NewsPageModule`.

Comment: done (Updated question)

Answer (score 1):

Update you navigate function call :)

```
 this.router.navigate(['/news'], { queryParams: { page: 2 } });
```

then

```
export class NewsPage implements OnInit {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            ...
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is coming late, but subscribe to params in your constructor instead of ngOnInit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31678538)

Answer (score -1):

Subscribing to route params is deprecated, now you can access following

```
this.id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
```

Comment: This is not the case. [As the Angular team has stated](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/43529#issuecomment-926026010): "There are no current plans to remove `params` or `queryParams` and there's no benefit to advising against their use." Subscribing to the params or queryParams observable is a perfectly valid approach.